# Sitelock scan my wordpress site and have an fatal error

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, sitelock

I got an error from Sitelock dashboard. What does that mean?

put: /tmp/sitelock_find_5199431.php: Fatal error: max-retries exceeded[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LxZZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Jess,

This is a temporary file that our scanner adds to test connectivity to the server being scanned, as well as file permissions and write capabilities. This might mean that the FTP user connected to SMART needs to have increased permissions, but it also might just be that there was a connectivity issue with the server when SMART tried to scan.

I hope this helps!
~Cj